# Adding a space before and after the text in UILabel using the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uilabel

How to add a space before and after the text in UILabel using storyboard.

Here is an example of label with a background.

[image]

Comment: This is ridiculously easy so what's the hard part for you?

Comment: sorry if it seems easy to you but am new to Swift.

Comment: How I can do it in using the storyboard.

Comment: Do _what_ in using the storyboard? Make the label wider? Make it wider. Make the text start and end with a space? Make it start and end with a space. What's the trouble?

Comment: adding a space before and after text in UILabel so the text isn't stuck at both edges.

Comment: Set the text as `" 2 answer "` (note the spaces) to pad it.

Comment: Manually I know that!!. I mean how to do it as custom for any UILabel.

Comment: But "custom for any label" would not be _in the storyboard_. You would have to do that in _code_. You'd use a custom UILabel subclass, for example. That's easy. But you ruled that out when you said it had to be done _in the storyboard_.

Comment: Can I do it if I changed the text form plain to attributed?? BTW I think we can do many things in the storyboard without the need of code. Maybe you love to write it but the features in the storyboard in UILabel is enormous.

Comment: An attributed string can add margins, yes. But UILabel might not respond to that very well. And you'd have to do it for _every single label_. If you're going to do that, why not just add the spaces to each one? How can you reject the spaces idea and then go for the margins idea? That's insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is:

- Use auto layout in the storyboard.
- Use a UILabel subclass that overrides `intrinsicContentSize` to be a little wider than the default.

For example:

```
extension CGSize {
    func sizeByDelta(dw dw:CGFloat, dh:CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(self.width + dw, self.height + dh)
    }
}

class MyWiderLabel : UILabel {
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return super.intrinsicContentSize().sizeByDelta(dw: 20, dh: 0)    
    }
}
```

Now just set the class of every label in your storyboard to be a MyWiderLabel.