# How to fix UILabel padding issue?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UILabel and whenever I set its outlet the padding I created in Storyboards for it under attributed text disappears like it was never there. The text the stays stuck on the left side. How can I fix this issue?

```
@IBOutlet weak var mycoollabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    mycoollabel.text = "Wow"
}
```

Comment: What are you using to set the padding?

Comment: @TwoStraws I set the Text property in Xcode to attributed then went to 'line indent and put 7 pixels

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34054468/341994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: OP clarified in a comment that they are setting their padding using attributed text in Interface Builder.

The problem here is a confusion between **text** and **attributed text**, or, because these are code, it's `text` and `attributedText`.

On iOS, lots of things have a `text` property, and it's just a simple string of text that gets displayed somewhere without any sort of formatting. Usually the formatting is attached to the object that is showing the text, e.g. a label has a text colour and alignment properties that make its `text` look however you want.

On iOS, most (all?) of those things also have an `attributedText` property, which is a very different beast. Attributed text contains a string but also specific formatting instructions required to display that string – text attributes, hence the name.

So, OP is creating an attributed text configuration in their storyboard, then, in code, modifying the `text` property. This will overwrite their formatted string with a plain string, losing its layout configuration.

If you're looking to create an attributed string with a first line indent, you should try this:

```
let ps = NSMutableParagraphStyle();
ps.firstLineHeadIndent = 50

let attrs = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: ps]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, world!", attributes: attrs)

label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Note that there are a few different options available to you here, so you might need to find the right type of indent for your precise needs. If you right-click on `NSMutableParagraphStyle` and choose Jump To Definition you'll see all the options.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer and it woks great! May I ask what if I didn't use attributed text but instead just plain and tried this?

Comment: You're welcome – I'm glad it worked. If you use Plain you're just setting the `text` property, so there will be no indent in the storyboard or in your original code. Given your requirement to have an indent, you should use `attributedText`, starting with my example above.

Comment: thanks again! btw I just clicked on your name and realized you're the person behind Hacking With Swift! I learned a lot from there.

Answer (score 1):

That's because a `UILabel` can have either plain text or attributed text. You set attributed text in the storyboard, and add some formatting (padding, etc.). Then, in code, you override that text (and all its formatting) with plain text.

If you want to keep the formatting, you need to set the label's `attributedText` property. And add all the necessary formatting to the `NSAttributedString` object you create for that.